# Concept for OTP with Time limit

Tags: java, time, calendar, one-time-password

Programme A:

Hash(Username, password and nowtime())

*nowtime() is defined as:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.getTime()
```

Programme B:

Hash(Username, password and nowtime())

*Programme B does a loop (up 15 sec) and each nowtime() is defined as:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, -1);
```

Though time from both programme matches, the OTP produced from the same hash function is different. I do not need code, please help me to understand sync time between 2 programme.

Comment: What is the implementation of Hash, which class it belongs to?

Comment: MD5 hash. Then I did int pin = (int)(hashtext.hashCode() % 1e6); to get the PIN

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar.getTime()` returns the time with a resolution of one milli second. Therefore the milli second values will surely be different on both computers (or they are only the same by pure luck).

To go with your solution you have to set the milli seconds to `0` before processing

```
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

then you should have at least one match.